# How would one keep the variable labels of factors after modifications?

Tags: r, forcats

How best would one retaining the variable labels after say you make modifications in the factors. I noticed that the variable labels are dropped when you apply slight modifications in group of variables. Below is an example of the code where the variable labels are dropped:

```
library(tidyverse) # forcats and dplyr

set.seed(2021) # Reproducibility


mydata <- tibble(
  a1 = factor(round(runif(20, 1, 3)),
              labels = c("Yes", "No", "N/A")),
  a2 = factor(round(runif(20, 1, 3)),
              labels = c("Received", "Not Received", "N/A")),
  a3 = round(rnorm(20, 2, 1)))
attr(mydata$a1, "label") <- "Exposed"
attr(mydata$a2, "label") <- "Receipt of treatment"
attr(mydata$a3, "label") <- "Dosage"

str(mydata) # There are variable labels as assigned

mydata <- mydata %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~fct_collapse(., NULL = "N/A")))

 str(mydata) # Variables labels for factors are dropped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#attributes) it is mentioned that attributes should generally be thought of as ephemeral. This means that most operations will not preserve attributes you set. This includes the variable labels you set in the example.

If you really need to preserve the labels as attributes, you can do so using S3 classes. However, this solution is very involved, because you need to write generic functions for every function you apply to your labelled objects.

In the case of the provided example, this would look something like the following. First we define a class constructor and apply the class to the columns in the dataset.

```r
    library(dplyr)
    library(forcats)

    new_labelled <- function(x, label){
      stopifnot(is.character(label))
      structure(x, class = c("labelled", attr(x, "class", TRUE)), label = label)
    }
    
    set.seed(2021) # Reproducibility
    
    mydata <- tibble(
      a1 = factor(round(runif(20, 1, 3)),
                  labels = c("Yes", "No", "N/A")),
      a2 = factor(round(runif(20, 1, 3)),
                  labels = c("Received", "Not Received", "N/A")),
      a3 = round(rnorm(20, 2, 1))) %>%
      mutate(
        a1 = new_labelled(a1, "Exposed"),
        a2 = new_labelled(a2, "Receipt of treatment"),
        a3 = new_labelled(a3, "Dosage"))

    str(mydata) # Variable labels are applied
```

Next we need to implement generics for `fct_collapse`:

```r
    fct_collapse2 <- function(.f, ..., other_level=NULL){
      UseMethod("fct_collapse2")
    }
    
    fct_collapse2.labelled <- function(.f, ..., other_level=NULL){
      stopifnot(is.factor(.f))
      label <- attr(.f, "label", TRUE)
      new_labelled(NextMethod(), label)
    }
    
    fct_collapse2.factor <- function(.f, ..., other_level=NULL){
      fct_collapse(.f, ..., other_level)
    }
```

Which allows us to preserve the labels:

```r
    mydata <- mydata %>%
      mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~fct_collapse2(., NULL = "N/A")))

    str(mydata) # The labels are preserved
```

In most cases, it is probably easier to store the labels somewhere and add them when all data manipulation is done, than it is to implement generics for every function you apply to your labelled objects.

Comment: I would actually store all the variables in a list then add them back after the manipulation is done. Your approach is very enlightening especially in dealing with the core of the language. Very useful.